# Prevent Bootstrap .table-responsive style from cropping a tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am having some problem with Bootstrap's `table-responsive` style.
[image]

I have tried some code here https://codepen.io/arindamx01/pen/gJOqxK to make the full tooltip visible. I have tried without `.table-responsive` class. Without `.table-responsive` class it works well: I  can see the tooltip by hovering on time. But when I add `.table-responsive` I can't see the total tooltip. The tooltip appears cropped at the bottom, and a long scroll bar appears on the right side of the  table.

Expected display:
[image]

Comment: What Popup?, can you add more details

Comment: sorry i have made a mistake it's a tooltip please hover on time section.

Comment: Check my answer it is working now

Comment: why This qustion is down voted can anyone tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change following css to `relative` to `absolute`

```
.tooltipItem_dist {
    position: absolute;
}
```

https://codepen.io/kashmiriguide/pen/gJOyjW

Comment: thanks @learning. can you please tell why is it downvoted the question

Comment: I didn't down-vote your question someone else might have, some user down-vote but don't give any reason for down-vote unfortunately .....

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use bootstrap **`.table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}`** [breakpoint specific](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#breakpoint-specific):

Comment: i already know it but I need someThing in custom css according to  that work

Comment: hmm... I think it is the best way since you are using bootstrap, if you want additional customization you can create another custom class and simply append it to element's class

Answer (score 1):

The *"problem"* (notice the quote) is that by using `.table-responsive` in your wrapper `<div>` changes it's default `overflow` behavior.
So when your tooltip appears it gets *trap* inside your `<div class="table-responsive">` wrapper.
To solve this just set the `overflow: visible;` to it.

About possible implications, well you will lose the ability to scroll horizontally on mobile, in that case you can write media query to restore the functionality on mobile devices, because you will not need the `tooltip` on a mobile anyway.

https://codepen.io/jose-guzman-ojeda/pen/wbvZEp

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below solution update your css accordingly.

```
.table-responsive { overflow-x: visible }
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
.table-responsive { overflow-y: visible }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions

Method 1:

```
.tooltipItem_dist{
  position: absolute;
}
```

It will be positioned related directly to the HTML element (the page itself).

An important thing to keep in mind while using absolute positioning is to make sure it is not overused, otherwise, it can lead to a maintenance nightmare.

Method 2:

```
.table-responsive{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

I will go with method 2.

Answer (score -1):

do you have try to add meta viewport?

```
<meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: yes I have already added. please see My tooltip hidden when i use table responsive.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.tooltipItem_dist:hover .tooltipItem {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.tooltipItem_dist{
  position: relative;
}
.tooltipItem_dist .tooltipItem {  
    top: 100%;
}
.tooltipItem {
  color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 30px);
    width: 160px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50% , 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50% , 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50% , 0);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
              <table class="table table-hover noMargin arUinqueteable">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>POS</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>AV PACE</th>
                    <th>TIME</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="results_section">  
                   <tr class="resultTotalTr "> <!--log_user_active-->
                        <td class="blue">1</td>
                        <td class="blue">Subha Dev <!--1--><!--Limpopo--></td>
                        <td class="blue">00:07:23</td>
                        <td class="black tooltipItem_dist">04:04:04
                        <div class="tooltipItem">
                            <ul>
                                <li><span>SWIM</span>  04:23:04</li>
                                <li><span>T1</span> sdfsdf</li>
                                <li><span>BIKE</span></li>
                                <li><span>T2</span></li>
                                <li><span>RUN</span></li>
                                <li><span>TOTAL</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        <td><!--<span>PB</span>--></td>
                        <td><!--<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>--></td>
                  </tr>
                                                                                                      
                 
                   <tr class="resultTotalTr "> <!--log_user_active-->
                        <td class="blue">2</td>
                        <td class="blue">Subha Dev <!--1--><!--Limpopo--></td>
                        <td class="blue">00:09:43</td>
                        <td class="black tooltipItem_dist">05:21:01
                        <div class="tooltipItem">
                            <ul>
                                <li><span>SWIM</span>  04:23:04</li>
                                <li><span>T1</span> sdfsdf</li>
                                <li><span>BIKE</span></li>
                                <li><span>T2</span></li>
                                <li><span>RUN</span></li>
                                <li><span>TOTAL</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        <td><!--<span>PB</span>--></td>
                        <td><!--<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>--></td>
                  </tr>
                                                                                                      
                 
                   <tr class="resultTotalTr "> <!--log_user_active-->
                        <td class="blue">3</td>
                        <td class="blue">Subha Dev <!--1--><!--Limpopo--></td>
                        <td class="blue">00:18:56</td>
                        <td class="black tooltipItem_dist">10:25:01
                        <div class="tooltipItem">
                            <ul>
                                <li><span>SWIM</span>  04:23:04</li>
                                <li><span>T1</span> sdfsdf</li>
                                <li><span>BIKE</span></li>
                                <li><span>T2</span></li>
                                <li><span>RUN</span></li>
                                <li><span>TOTAL</span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        <td><!--<span>PB</span>--></td>
                        <td><!--<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>--></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  
                </tbody>
              </table>
              
                          </div>
```

Comment: edited answer..take ans run the same code in code pen it will work as per your requirement..in stackoverflow console it is showing scroll bar but there it wont show.just try with the above solution